# authorization failed error when flutter pub get

Tags: flutter, dart

I download a flutter project and want to run it. when run flutter pub get in command line, this error

```
Because eschool depends on win32 any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.
Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
    dart pub token add https://pub.dev
```

after run "dart pub token add https://pub.dev":

```
Enter secret token:
Requests to "https://pub.dev" will now be authenticated using the secret token.
```

what is secret token and https://pub.dev?

run "dart pub token add https://pub.dev" not solve my problem.`your text`

Comment: Can you please provide your pubspec.yaml?